# How to return a count result of only one column?

Tags: select, frequency, informix

I have a table like this:

[image]

And would like to make a selection by period (date field), where I could return the registers, and a column with the total of registres matched with only one column.

For example:
If I use this query:

```
SELECT date, product_type, operation, unit
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-08-26 00:00:00' AND '2019-08-26 23:59:59';
```

It must return:

[image]

But I wish I could return one more column, with the total of operations regardless period like this:

[image]

Where in this case, 6 is the frequency that "ajoy" appears in the table.

IMPORTANT! If I select a period where two or more operations are returned, so the query must be able to return their frequency as well.

Comment: Please remember that tables have names — and gives us a name to work with.  Otherwise, people have to invent names on the fly, which can lead to lots of different names in the answers (if there is more than one answer), which makes it hard to compare answers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right. Sorry for that. I'll consider this in a further question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used part of your data and will include what I had for data in the table, but I believe this is what you want

```
create table mytab (job int, operations char(8), prod char(8),  
ts_date datetime year to minute, unit int) lock mode row;

insert into mytab values(22, "ajoy","arrow","2020-05-11 08:51", 20);
insert into mytab values(22, "ajoy","arrow","2020-05-11 08:51", 20);
insert into mytab values(22, "ajoy","arrow","2020-05-11 08:51", 20);

insert into mytab values(22, "ajoy","arrow","2020-04-11 14:15", 20);
insert into mytab values(22, "ajoy","arrow","2020-04-11 14:15", 20);
insert into mytab values(22, "ajoy","arrow","2020-04-11 14:15", 20);

insert into mytab values(23, "dinn","curve","2020-05-11 08:51",1);
insert into mytab values(23, "dinn","point","2020-05-11 08:51",1);
insert into mytab values(23, "dinn","arrow","2020-04-11 08:51",1);
```

The query:

```
select job, operations, prod, ts_date, unit, (select count(*) from mytab b 
where b.operations = a.operations) total_operation  from mytab a where 
a.ts_date between "2020-05-11 08:50" and "2020-05-11 08:59"
```

The above query gave me the following results which is I think what you were asking for:

```
    job operations prod     ts_date                 unit  total_operation

     22 ajoy       arrow    2020-05-11 08:51          20                6
     22 ajoy       arrow    2020-05-11 08:51          20                6
     22 ajoy       arrow    2020-05-11 08:51          20                6
     23 dinn       curve    2020-05-11 08:51           1                3
     23 dinn       point    2020-05-11 08:51           1                3
```

This example is small and has doesn't include/account for indexes you may which to put on the table to speed query performance.